# Sorting multiple columns based on product name in Excel

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have a question about sorting multiple columns based on name. I know this is a job for vlookup or index match based on my Google results, but I am having trouble creating my solution. I am creating a worksheet that will have two columns for everyday of the month.
So the column names across will be: Product, Sales, BLANK, Product, Sales, etc) Some of the columns have more products and I want all the columns to have the same order.
So for example if the prduct was it Column A, but not column D, there would be a blank row in D to indicate this.
Can someone walk me through creating this formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option of keeping the data in table format (example below), then Pivot table will be an easy solution. 
Data (wouldn't have bullets but I couldn't format it differently here):

- Date     Product  Sales
- Jan 1    prod1    $1,235.00
- Jan 1    prod2    $5,104.00
- Jan 1    prod3    $21.00
- Jan 2    prod1    $254.00

Select all your data, then in the Menu bar click on Insert -> Pivot Table -> Ok. Choose date for your Column Headers, Product for your Row Headers and Sales for Values. Hope this helps!

Comment: Pivot Table was a thought I had too, but the person I'm creating this for wants a running list with columns for everyday.

Comment: I still think Pivot is a more reliable solution in your case, it can have running totals and can be formatted as needed. If the Pivot is absolutely not an option, you can have the date displayed using conditional sum formula. To do that, have you products listed going down for every day of the month and dates listed horizontally. 

(Continued in the next comment)

Comment: Example (assuming your source data is in columns A:C, organized in table format similar to what I have above and you're presenting the data in the same sheet, just for example), starting in cell M1, you can use this formula 
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,M$1,$B:$B,M3) Where $C:$C is source column with sale numbers, $A:$A is source column with dates, M$1 is 1st date you're reporting, M3 is first product you're reporting.